# How do I output a category and its custom field on a node listing?

Tags: 7, views, entities, taxonomy-terms

We've got a content type that has a Category field. The Category taxonomy has a tagline (custom field). I also have a view (Page type) that outputs all nodes of my content type, grouped by the category. So the output is sort-of like:

```
Category

Node
Node

Category

Node
...
```

But I'd like to display the category with its tagline (a custom field), like:

```
Category - Tagline

Node
Node

Category - Tagline

Node
...
```

But I can't figure out how to do this. I've been trying to use Rewrite Results to customize my resultant markup, but the tagline content isn't available as a token, nor is the description. According to the Rewrite Results' Replacement panel, only the formatter-based output and term ID are available.

What is the correct way to display the category's tagline, preferably using Rewrite Results?

Comment: Do you want a list of the terms for the current node, including the tagline field for each term? or something else?

Comment: @rooby Technically, there can only be 1 of these categories per node. I also have the "group by" parameter set on the view itself. So the category breaks up the list of nodes. So technically it uses the grouping template to output. And I can't quite figure out how to tell Drupal to format the link.

Comment: So is the question how to make the group heading a link?

Comment: @rooby Please see my latest edits.